# Массив объектов JS

Tags: javascript

Столкнулся с таким вот вопросом:

```
 var car=new Object();
car[0]=
{
    Mark: "BMW",
    Color: "Black"
};
car[1]=
{

    Mark: "VW",
    Color: "White"
};
var prop='Mark';
console.log(car.length);
for(var i=0;i<2;i++)
{
    console.log(car[i][prop]);
}
```

Как вы видите, я создал (а может и не правильно создал), массив объектов , к каждому приписал по два свойства. И пытаюсь пройти по массиву.... Но длину массива получить не могу, что я не так  делаю, подскажите. Сильно не ругайтесь с JS только начал, до этого был на C#. Спасибо!

Comment: _я создал (а может и не правильно создал), массив объектов._ Вы создали объект, а не массив объектов.

Comment: Вы не правильно создали массив. Массив - это Array, а не Object. На C# разве массив это Object?

Comment: Нет. на C# совершенно иначе массив объектов объявляется.
Извините, тогда следует мой глупый вопрос, как правильно объявить массив объектов?

Comment: var car = new Array();

Comment: Т.е. в любом случае, объявляю, как массив, а далее работаю уже с элементами массива, как с объектами. Правильно понял?)

Comment: Начните [отсюда](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections#Array_object)

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо всем, кто помог. Решение проблемы:

```
var car = new Array();
```

Comment: А вот так вот делать не стоит

Comment: var car = []   вот так

Answer (score 0):

тебе надо было всего добавить скобки

```
var car=new Object();
car['0']=
{
    Mark: "BMW",
    Color: "Black"
};
car['1']=
{

    Mark: "VW",
    Color: "White"
};
var prop='Mark';
```

длина обекта

```
Object.keys(car).length
```

Comment: Ммм, как это работает?
Если долго объяснять, буду благодарен за ссылку)

Comment: @Valera, никак это не работает, тот же самый код, что и у тебя :)

Comment: @Grundy, но оно реально работает ХД
Просто, я не понимаю, что делает [' ']..)
Очень хочу разобраться

Comment: Эм, ну да, для цикла работает, длину не выводит. Я понял, что мы сделали, спасибо. Но это всё же не массив объектов, @Grundy, вы были правы!

Comment: ну длину можно так Object.keys(car).length

Comment: @Санитариум, но это всё же не будет являться массивом из объектов.

Comment: ну да конечно у